# can't deserialize guava type with GWTP-Rest + jackson-guava from Spring service using guava-datatype

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, gwtp

I use GWTP-Rest and i need to deserialize an dto which contains an ListMultimap. All the elements of the dto are deserialize but not the ListMultimap. below the code of dto. JsonAnnotation are working and come from the correct artifactId which is compatible with gwt-jackson. I imports with maven gwt-guava-jackson and inherits the module.

public class GetdtoMobileResult implements ExpirableResult, DtoData {

```
@JsonProperty("diffusions")
private ListMultimap<Integer, Diffusion> diffusions;

private TimeInterval visibleRange;

@JsonProperty("ttl")
private long ttl;

private dtoHourRange hourRange;

GetTVGuideMobileResult() {
    super();
}

public GetTVGuideMobileResult(
        final ArrayListMultimap<Integer, Diffusion> diffusions,
        final TimeInterval visibleRange, final long ttl, final MediamatHourRange range) {
    super();
    this.diffusions = diffusions;
    this.visibleRange = visibleRange;
    this.ttl = ttl;
    this.hourRange = range;
}

@JsonIgnore
@Override
public ListMultimap<ChannelId, Diffusion> getDiffusions() {
    return ArrayListMultimap.create();
}

@JsonProperty("diffusions")
public ListMultimap<Integer, Diffusion> getdiffusions()
{
    return diffusions;
}

@Override
public TimeInterval getVisibleRange() {
    return visibleRange;
}

@JsonProperty("ttl")
@Override
public long ttl() {

    return ttl;
}

@Override
public dtoHourRange getHourRange() {
    return hourRange;
}

// #### setter add to able deserialization on client side mobile. ######
@JsonProperty("diffusions")
public void setDiffusions(final ListMultimap<Integer, Diffusion> diffusions) {
    this.diffusions = diffusions;
}

public void setHourRange(final dtoHourRange hourRange) {
    this.hourRange = hourRange;
}

@JsonProperty("ttl")
public void setTtl(final long ttl) {
    this.ttl = ttl;
}

public void setVisibleRange(final TimeInterval visibleRange) {
    this.visibleRange = visibleRange;
}
```

}

I receive the correct object from server {"diffusions":{"..."} ,...}. Serialization is doing by the lib jackson-datatype-guava, which if i correctly understood is using by jackson-guava. Interface which are implements define getter of the object, and implements Serializable.

I have another problem's, probably linked to his, my ListMultimap use normaly an dto as key which wrap an integer, but jackson tell me that my dto is not supported as map's key. Code of my dto :

public class DtoId implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * serial version Uid
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5816632906385308130L;

private int id;

DtoId() {
    // for serialization
}

public DtoId(final int id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    ChannelId other = (ChannelId) obj;
    if (id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem's come from bad dependency between project on guava. I provided same version of guava to the client, shared & server, now serialization works, sorry to the bad question.

Second error continue to occurs, i will post this on an other page.